# i am working on sparklyr. trying to write my data into postgresql, but its taking forever

Tags: r, sparklyr

My configurations:

```
config = spark_config()
config$`sparklyr.cores.local` <- 3
config$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "10G"
config$`spark.yarn.executor.memory.overhead` <- "512mb"
sc = spark_connect(master = "local", config = config)
```

Code used to write file:

```
spark_write_jdbc(final, name = "test",
                              options = list(url = "jdbc:postgresql://172.XXX.X.XXX/test",
                                             user = "xxxx",
                                             password = "xxxx",
                                            memory = FALSE ))
```

I might have approximately 40million rows.